# how to echo custom attribute value in crosssell.phtml in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, cross-sells, custom-attributes

this is my crosssell.phtml code:

```
<div class="crosssell">
    <p><?php echo $this->__('THIS PRODUCT IS ALSO AVAILABLE IN ') ?></p>
    <ul id="crosssell-products-list">
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li class="item">              
            <div class="product-details">
                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>                       
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('crosssell-products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
```

Now I have a custom attribute say 'colour'. I want to show this custom attribute value in crossell.phtml in the foreach loop.
My attempt so far:

```
<?php echo $attr= $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('colour')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item); ?>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

## config.xml

Magento checks this XPath in the `config.xml` to get the attributes which are loaded automatically with a collection:

```
/config/frontend/product/collection/attributes
```

Example: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml:721`

To add an attribute to the cart page, you need to load the attribute during the product loading of the `quote_item_collection`, this can be done via XML too, the XPath is:

```
/config/global/sales/quote/item/product_attributes
```

## Observer

Implement an observer and listen to the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection` for adding attributes to the product list block and on `catalog_product_collection_load_before` to add attributes to *ALL* collection loadings.

We have plenty of explanation here on magento SE and in the web how to implement an observer, e.g. [from apptha](http://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-observers-and-dispatching-events-explained-explicitly/).

Inside the observer method we just have to add things to the collection:

```
public function catalogBlockProductListCollection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('MY_ATTRIBUTE');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('size', 'XL'); // you can although filter if you want!
}
```

## Attribute used_in_product_list

The third alternative is (as @Christian-Ducrot describes) to change the setting of the attribute for `used_in_product_listing` to yes.

This can either be done in the attribute backend, while creating an attribute with `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute` and setting `used_in_product_listing` to `1` or later with `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::updateAttribute`

Comment: for me I could only see `/config/frontend/product/collection/attributes` being used for one setup script that is used to set the flag `used_in_product_listing` but maybe I missed something

Comment: \Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::getProductCollectionAttributes

Comment: which I can only find used in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.57-0.7.58.php`

Answer (score 1):

To get custom attributes in product collections you have to set "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes" in product attribute settings. After reindexing your code should work as expected.

[image: Used in Product Listing]

Comment: Ok, I have done it.